# Displaying Certain Row of Query Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

So when i run this query I get 6 results of data

```
Select Title
From products.features
where productid = '172'
```

Here is the data:

1. 312-109
2. UL Rated 94V-O, Black, 10% Glass Filled 6 Nylon per ASTM D4066
   PA210G11
3. Improves PCB and system cooling
4. Supports any spacing, any length, and any PCB thickness

I only want to display the 2nd row in the results though..

UL Rated 94V-O, Black, 10% Glass Filled 6 Nylon per ASTM D4066 PA210G11

Comment: 2nd row of what order?

Comment: You need to define an order, otherwise how does SQL Server know which top 5 you want, and what "2nd" means? Imagine I dropped a bag of marbles on the floor, then you walked in the room. Could you tell me which marble hit the floor 2nd?

Comment: Well, you need to `order`, otherwise your results won't be consistent.

Comment: Im trying to select the second row of a result of 6 rows that appear when i search my data and i can't use a where clause

Comment: 6 rows, top 5? If you can't get the details straight, how do you expect a useful answer? Also what does "i can't use a where clause" mean? Why not?

Comment: @user3014698, you can't use where clause? or you can't use order by clause?

Comment: Again, your 2nd row depend on the order of the result set. Please read @AaronBertrand's 1st comment.

Comment: So when i run this query Select Title
From products.features
where productid = '172'   i get like 5 rows of data i only want the 2nd row to display though

Comment: And there is no other column that helps distinguish the specific title result

Comment: And is it okay if the 2nd row changes the next time you run the exact same query with the exact same data?

Comment: No it has to stay the same since its pulling the title of 6 results based on the product id

Comment: No where clause? but you have where clause in your question??

Comment: What I meant there is no other where clause besides where productid = '172' that i can use

Comment: Your question is still confusing after the edit... is your data just a long string??? Do you want to chat so I can better help you? I think you're very confused.

Comment: Question title is very confusing !

Comment: If we could chat that would be awesome.  And what I'm really trying to do is bring the results of the 2nd row but when i run the query using the where productid ='172' i get 6 results

Comment: I'm not sure how much more clearly this can be stated. If you need the  2nd row to be the same every single time than you MUST I repeat MUST use an order by clause to determine the order of the results.

Comment: What an absolute and sad waste of people's time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with cte as
(
    Select TOP 5 Title, Title_Row = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Title asc)
    From products.features
    Where productid = '172'
)
Select *
From cte
Where Title_Row = 2
Order by Title
```

Edit, added Order by Title.

Comment: This WORKED! Thank you for understanding my poorly written question!! I just changed ORDER BY Title to ID and it worked the way I wanted it to thanks :)

Comment: @user3014698 oh, so it's ordered by ID! Genius! Next time you may want to mention that there *is* a column you can use to determine order and what 2nd means. Not knowing this led to how many silly comments on your question???

Comment: This answer has a `TOP 5` (in the cte) without `ORDER BY`, so it is potentially wrong. Please add `ORDER BY Title` or remove the `TOP 5`

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you're trying to order by Title

```
select Top 1 Title
from (
   Select Top 2 Title
   From products.features
   where productid = '172'
   order by Title asc
) a
order by Title desc
```

What you keep leaving out is the Order By. If you don't have a order by... your result will not be guaranteed every run. Sort of random.

Comment: select top 1 
from (
Select Title
From products.features
where productid = '172'
)
order by ID desc gives error

Comment: did you just copy and paste that? what i've posted is just conceptual.. you'll have to fill in some blanks. *headache*

Comment: I re-edited the question, I don't think I explained correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your help i now understand that i needed an order by clause!